# How to separate a string with "|" as the separator? How to store it in two variable

Tags: c++, variables, stdstring, separator

I have a string.

```
Input:

std::string kind = 0123|0f12;
```

We have the separator "|".

I would like to store that two value into two variable. How can i do that?

```
Output:
    std::string kind1 = 0123;

    std::string kind2 = 0f12;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string kind = "0123|0f12";
std::size_t found = kind.find("|");
if (found != std::string::npos)
{
   std::string kind1 = kind.substr(0,found-1);
   std::string kind2 = kind.substr(found+1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think -1 don't need because it cuts the last character.

Answer (score 1):

Use [find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), [substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) and [erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) member function of `std::string`. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "0123|0f12";
    std::string delimiter = "|";

    size_t pos = 0;
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
        std::string token = s.substr(0, pos);
        vec.push_back(token);
        s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }
    if (!s.empty())
        vec.push_back(s);
    for (const auto& i: vec)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0123
0f12
```